# Spring autowire issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, annotations, autowired

i am running a unit tests and uses a Service class to perform some business logic. however, the unit tests fails saying that the service class is null dispite setting up the Autorwire annotations for it.

below is my unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/FreedomSpring-servlet.xml" })
public class UserControllerTest
{
    private UserController controller;

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private String jsonUser = "{ \"username\":\"jonneymendoza\",\"emailAddress\":\"jon@google.com\", \"password\":\"12345678\",\"firstName\":\"jono\", \"surname\":\"richy\", \"country\":\"united kingdom\",\"bio\":\"Bio stuff goes here about the user. where he comes from etc etc. all is well. lets go go go\" }";

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        controller = new UserController();

        assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateNewAccount()
    {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = controller
                                          .createNewAccount(new HttpEntity<String>(jsonUser));
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Here is the controller i am testing

```
@Controller
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String>createNewAccount(HttpEntity<String>request)
    {
        userService.registerNewUser( JSONObject.fromObject(request.getBody())); //fails here

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(null, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

The service class:

```
@Service("UserService")
@Transactional
public class UserService implements UserServiceInterface
{
    @Override
    public void registerNewUser(JSONObject user) throws InvalidDataException, JSONException
    {
        // parse json object to a User object
        User newUser = parseJsonObject(user);

        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

        userDao.addNewUser(newUser);
    }
}
```

My service-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Define services here -->

    <bean id="UserService" class="com.jr.freedom.user.UserService"></bean>
</beans>
```

My servlett:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <import resource="mvc-config.xml" />

    <import resource="service-config.xml" />

    <import resource="classpath:datasource-config.xml" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jr.freedom.controllers"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

And finally the error i recieve

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jr.freedom.controllers.UserController.createNewAccount(UserController.java:56)
    at com.jr.freedom.controllers.UserControllerTest.testCreateNewAccount(UserControllerTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: You need to use the application context to get an instance of your service and/or controller. If you just invoke the constructor like you do, nothing special would happen.

Comment: Forget about new operator for Spring beans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject (with some annotation) or retreive userController from the applicationContext so that Spring magic (i.e. injection or userService in your case) works.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/FreedomSpring-servlet.xml" })
public class UserControllerTest {

@Autowired
private UserController userController;

@Inject
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private String jsonUser = "{ \"username\":\"jonneymendoza\",\"emailAddress\":\"jon@google.com\", \"password\":\"12345678\",\"firstName\":\"jono\", \"surname\":\"richy\", \"country\":\"united kingdom\",\"bio\":\"Bio stuff goes here about the user. where he comes from etc etc. all is well. lets go go go\" }";

@Before
public void setup() {
    assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    assertNotNull(userController);

}
```

Comment: Looks like it worked! all i did was to add AutoWired to my controller as shown above it fixes the nullpointer. strange because on my setup method i create a controller object

Comment: When you create the controller object by hand (i.e. calling new Controller() ) : Spring do nothing to setup your object correctly. On the other hand, when you ask Spring to inject the bean : Spring will instatiate it and do the setup (i.e. looking at all bean field that requires an injection and perform this injection.